# Share an encrypted Image with other applications android

Tags: java, android, cryptography

I'm developing an application on android platform to encrypt images and i'm using bouncy castle library  and I'm doing fine with the encryption part but now when i get the encrypted image I can't send it through other applications like whatsapp and others because the encrypted image file is not recognized as an image file anymore so i cant send it.  so can i add anything to the encrypted image so other applications can recognize it as an image and transmitted through it or do somthing else ... thanks

Comment: My knowledge about encryption is little but maybe (just a thought!) if you only encrypt the data in a file and not the file header  you can get around this.

Comment: [Is it possible to store arbitrary data in an image file?](http://superuser.com/questions/357869/is-it-possible-to-store-arbitrary-data-in-an-image-file)

Comment: I have to encrypt everything but i thought about it the same way but by adding a fixed header but still don't know how to do it .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to transmit a ciphered message as an image, you need to define a custom protocol to wrap the ciphertext in some image exchange container format, for example PNG.

I wrote a simple [program](https://github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/ceci-n-est-pas-une-pipe) that encrypts an image (the message) and stores the ciphertext along side some meta information in a PNG-encoded container. The sources are on GitHub and the idea is:

1. generate the secret key
2. write headers to file
3. encrypt the message (an image) and write to file